# Find the control which mouse is over in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

Is there anyway when mouse moving find the control mouse is over on it? I mean if you have a dialog with some labels and text boxes, and the mouse move to label, notify me that label name, after that if move it to text box notify the text box name.

Comment: In your own program you can do everything, since you know position of all child windows. Generic way is using ChildWindowFromPoint API.

Comment: Windows don't have names.  A dialog template sets the control ID of the window, CWnd::GetDlgCtrlID() returns it.  This is of course not useful to the user at all, little point in actually writing this code.

Comment: @HansPassant none the less a perfectly valid and helpful point if the OP is hellbent on hunting for one thing when they should be looking for something else. Good info.

Answer (score 1):

If you handle WM_MOUSEMOVE within your dialog, you can grab the mouse position, convert it to dialog coordinates, and determine what control lies underneath the cursor point.

Comment: `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is sent to the control underneath the mouse cursor (unless the control is disabled). `DispatchMessage` already determined which control is underneath the mouse cursor. You don't have to find the answer to a question the system already answered for you.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I came to this code which let me know if the mouse cursor is over my control in a dialog box.

```
//Handling mouse move in mfc dialog

void CDialogRoll::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{

    CRect rect1;

    m_FrameArea.GetClientRect(&rect1);    //control rectangle

    m_FrameArea.ClientToScreen(&rect1)
    ScreenToClient(&rect1);               //dialog coordinates`
    if (point.x >= rect1.left && point.x <= rect1.right && point.y >= rect1.top && 
          point.y <= rect1.bottom) {
        char str[100];
        sprintf(str, "%d-%d", point.x - rect1.left, point.y - rect1.top);

    }
    CDialogEx::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```